# Shortcodes not resolved in AJAX call response

Tags: filters, shortcode, ajax

I have a simple function, which returns the content of a page with the given pageID:

```
function get_page_content(){

    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

    $page_data = get_page($id);

      echo apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
    //echo do_shortcode($page_data -> post_content);
    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_page_content', 'get_page_content' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_page_content', 'get_page_content' );
```

But after an Update of WP and some Plugins the returned content still containes unresolved shortcodes like so:

```
[vc_row row_type=“row“ use_row_as_full_screen_section=“no“ type=“grid“ text_align=“left“ background_image_as_pattern=“without_pattern“][vc_column width=“1/1″]
```

The shortcodes come from a Plugin called **Visual Composer** (which got updated in the process to the latest version)

**Question:**
How can i render the shortcodes befor i return the content?
I tried both

```
echo apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
```

and

```
echo do_shortcode($page_data -> post_content);
```

Comment: Applying `the_content` filter should be sufficient - I'm guessing Visual Composer registers some of its shortcode conditionally i.e. not when your AJAX fires.

Comment: I tried it with shortcodes of other plugins and they don't work as well unfortunaltely

Comment: That's because all the above work is hook into `init` which is always fired before `wp` hook which content filters and shortcodes are hooked into.. Try this paste and let me know if that would be the answer http://pastebin.com/KbBuzjVi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since version 4.9 visual composer added shortcode lazy loading. To use VC shortcodes on AJAX content use this function before printing the content `WPBMap::addAllMappedShortcodes();`. So below code may help you,

```
function get_page_content(){

    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

    $page_data = get_page($id);

    WPBMap::addAllMappedShortcodes();

    echo apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_page_content', 'get_page_content' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_page_content', 'get_page_content' );
```

Answer (score 1):

`the_content` is usually "executed" in the context of a loop when all relevant global data is set. You should try to mimic it by using code like

```
function get_page_content(){
    global $post;

    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

    $post = get_page($id);
    setup_postdata($post);
      echo apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
    //echo do_shortcode($page_data -> post_content);
    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_page_content', 'get_page_content' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_page_content', 'get_page_content' );
```

This may or may not be enough depending on the specific checks the plugin does, and you might need to construct the main query object probably by using [query_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/) (one of the very rare cases in which it is ok to use that function).