# Run visual composer code in php page

Tags: shortcode

I am working on a site built in visual composer/wp bakery.  I do not want to work in the admin but in a php file.

How can I get code like

```
[vc_column_text]
<h3><a href="home">home</a></h3>
[/vc_column_text]
```

to parse from a a php file, rather than WP admin?

Comment: Those are shortcodes, it'll make more sense and be much easier to search if you think of them as VC shortcodes rather than VC code

Comment: Why use Visual Composer at all if you want to write the code? Seems to defeat the purpose.

Comment: because the site is written in visual composer.  I am just working with it.  If I deactivate the plugin it does not make HTML code but errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on Toms comment this will work:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( ' 
[vc_column_text]
<h3><a href="home">home</a></h3>
[/vc_column_text]
' );?>
```

Comment: If anyone else is struggling with this, here's a solution that worked for me: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/230092/9041

Comment: Hey, I am having an issue with the do_shortcode function, I am getting all content of post containing the visual composer shortcode, I have called the function like this::  ```do_shortcode(get_the_content())``` but gives me an output like:: ```[vc_row][vc_column]  content ..... [/vc_row][/vc_column]```

Comment: I don't want to show these tags with content.

Comment: I dont fully understand your case but you need to activate the visual composer/wp bakery plugin in admin, then the [vc_row] will be parsed by that plugin.  If you do not want to use the plugin, you have to rewrite all the code

Answer (score 1):

You can just try this function `WPBMap::addAllMappedShortcodes();` and the shortcodes will disappear!

Comment: This may be a good answer to a different question, but the idea is to execute the shortcode, not to remove it